# Computing the inverse of a triangular matrix

Tags: matrices

Suppose $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is a nonsingular triangular matrix with inverse $B= [b_1,\ldots,b_n]$. The $k$th column $b_k$ of $B$ is the solution of the linear systems $Ab_k =e_k$. Write this system as a $2\times 2$ triangular block system and explain why we can find $b_k$ by solving the linear systems
\begin{align}
$A(k:n, k:n)b_k(k:n) &= I(k:n, k),\quad k=1,2,\ldots,n &&\text{(for $A$ lower triangular)}, \\
$A(1:k, 1:k)b_k(1:k) &= I(1:k, k),\quad k=n, n−1,\ldots,1 &&\text{(for $A$ upper triangular)}.
\end{align}

Is it possible to store the interesting part of $b_k$ in $A$ as soon as it is computed?

Answer (score 0):

If, e.g., $A$ is lower triangular, you can implement the inversion algorithm by overwriting the storage occupied by $A$. The inversion is essentially solving a system $AB=I$ with multiple right-hand sides composed of the columns of the identity matrix. Say, we want to compute the $k$-th column of $B$, that is, to solve the system
$$
Ab_k=e_k,
$$
where $e_k$ is zero except $k$-th component equal to one. Write it now in the partitioned form
$$
Ab_k=e_k\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & 0 \\
A_{21} & A_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_k
\\
d_k
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ e_1
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $A_{11}$ is $(k-1)\times (k-1)$. Note that since $A$ is nonsingular, both diagonal blocks $A_{11}$ and $A_{22}$ are nonsingular as well. We have hence
$$
A_{11}c_k=0\quad\text{and}\quad A_{21}c_k+A_{22}d_k=e_1.
$$
Therefore, 
$$
c_k=0\quad\text{and}\quad A_{22}d_k=e_1.
$$
Consequently, the rows $k,\ldots,n$ in the $k$-th column of the inverse are given by solving a "small" triangular system $A_{22}d_k=e_1$. Note that $d_k$ does not depend on the blocks $A_{11}$ and $A_{21}$, which can be safely rewritten by the columns $1,\ldots,k-1$ of the inverse.

In the case when $A$ is upper triangular, the order of the columns will be reversed, that is, you can overwrite the entries of $A$ with the entries of its inverse starting from the column $n$ down to $1$.